# Crystal Report - Last Page is blank

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which when  generated has a last page that is blank except for the page footer (which indicates the current page, as well as the report title).

This only occurs when the data displayed on the second last page completely fills the page.

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some (almost) empty group footer, which doesn't fit onto last (non-empty) page.

You have to set "New page after" option to some inner group footer section.

Comment: None of the inner group footer sections have the "New page after" option set.

I will look into the group footers to determine if any of them do not fit on the last page properly.

Comment: You may recolor them to make debugging easier :) Actually last page problems are sometimes really serious - we have even made line counters and split pages to avoid placing big group footer to last page and as few as 10 detail lines on previous.

Answer (score 42):

When you check the checkbox **New Page After**, you will see an icon just right to it. This icon represents **Formula Workshop**. Click this icon and type ***NOT OnLastRecord***.

Save and close the window, you are good to test this and praise me for the rest of your lives :)

Comment: Thanks and it did work! No doubt...I will praise you for the rest of my life..;)..

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the checkbox on the group footer, use a formula.

The one that I use is

```
not(OnLastRecord)
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is an old question, but I just had a similar problem.

In my case the last page was printing the Page header and nothing else.

It turns out that the fix for me was to **Right Click on the Report Footer** (Which had no contents) and **choose Hide**.

So it was basically putting in a blank report footer and including the page header with it...

Hope this helps...

Comment: You saved me! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 5):

+1 to Arvo because what he said is probably the case. I'll expand on it a little.

More than likely you have a section that will not totally fit on the second to last page so it spills over to a new page.

Some options you may be able to use are in the section expert are "Keep Together" which keeps all the lines of the section together, either on the current page (if there is room) or on the next (if not), or the "Suppress Blank Section". You could also try to shrink the height of the section, but this will probably not work in all cases.

As Arvo also said, make sure that you do not have the "New Page After" flag set for any of the sections as this could cause it as well.

Comment: I am currently already making use of the "Keep Together" property and at the moment suppress blank section is not being utilized on all defined sections.

At the moment simple decreasing the size of the group footer to half seems to have stopped the extra page from being generated. However, I will have to test more as you indicated this will probably not work in all cases.

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same situation and a good solution is to control the "New Page After" (in my case in the group footer) by a simple sentence, only doing it, when the current page is not the last.

With the option "New Page After" unchecked put a formula on it, clicking it's right formula button.

Code:

```
if(PageNumber = TotalPageCount) Then
    True
else
    False;
```

Saves a lot of troubles.

Greetings.

P.D. It's Crystal Syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate if you need a report footer. If don't, be sure supress this section on report.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to checking what other have mentioned above, after creating a new Blank Report, under Page Setup, the paper size for me was A4 by default. When I changed it to Letter, I would get a second blank page in the Print Preview as well as when physically printing to letter paper. Presumably this is due to going over the page boundaries. I was able to reduce the magins, and make the report content fit on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Or being on “Design” tab, under “Report Header” right click and select “**Fit Section**”

Comment: The "Fit Section" option is available for each section, so check which section you need to "Fit Section"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an image outside the paper design, i just align it and scaled it to fit my paper.

Answer (score 0):

For some this might happen when there is an unused section like report footer. Suppress the section, it will be resolved.