# Crystal Report - printing an extra page

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

Could anybody please tell me what's the problem with these crystal reports?

When I print the report, it prints two pages like in the image. I want to remove the last page printed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a group section in the report? Post  the report screenshot  for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to suppress the blank section via

To suppress/hide a section:

> Right-click on the section name on the left -> Select one of the two
>   options:
>
> 1. Hide (Drill-Down OK): this option allows you to double-click on the section in the report preview to see the hidden values
> 2. Suppress (No Drill-Down): this option does not allow you to see the hidden values in the report preview

https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/38218

[Crystal Reports Printing blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175048/crystal-reports-printing-blank-page)

[Crystal Report - Last Page is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166881/crystal-report-last-page-is-blank)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **Report Footer**  section.

> Section Expert --> Paging Tab -->New Page After

use `NOT OnLastRecord` in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind for the second box at the bottom appear a little higher position that current position, you  may go to the section expert of the section that display that box, and clear "Print at the bottom" checkbox.

Result :
The second box appear at higher position, and second page not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.
After lots of surfing, the issue got solved by following below steps:

1. Remove unnecessary sections.
2. Remove unnecessary grouping.
3. Suppress Report Footer Section.